# Copy /b and Findstr /v

Tags: cmd.exe, findstr

I'm trying to merge a lot of logs together that is in one folder.

This is what I've tried to do.

```
copy /b *.log test.log | findstr /V "xyz" test.log >> final_test.log
```

It doesn't seem to be working but it works if I were to do individually. Can someone correct me on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about what you really want.

For merging files, `copy /b *.log test.log` will do.
Tested on Windows 10.

Comment: I want to merge the files then use the results and findstr "xyz" test.log >> final_test.log

I know that this works if I was to do it as separately

Comment: @Yen Deng  Then you may want `copy /b *.log test.log && findstr /V "xyz" test.log >> final_test.log`